# Taylor series expansion of multiple terms

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble getting my head around the expansion of:
$$f(y+bhf(y))$$ 
I want to expand a function within a function. I have been given that 
$$f(y+hf(y))=f(y)+hf(y)f'(y)+\frac{h^2f(y)^2}{2}f''(y)+\cdots$$
I assume, therefore that my original expansion would follow from this as
$$f(y+bhf(y))=f(y)+bhf(y)f'(y)+\frac{b^2h^2f(y)^2}{2}f''(y)+\cdots$$
from which I can see the basic Taylor series form, but I don't quite understand where each bit has gone. How do the multiple parts expand out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. Using the standard Taylor Series:
$$f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\cdots$$
with $x=y+bhf(y)$ and $a=y$, the solution pops out.